# I got empty values when converting object to int with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I try to convert a list of columns from str object to integer using this method

```
df['A'] = pd.to_numeric(df['A'], errors='coerce')
df['A'] = df['A'].apply(np.int64)
```

NB: Type of column A is object

But I got this error `ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer`

I guess the problem is because there is some space in values exp

```
A
1 234
6 8374
```

I tried with this line of code to remove space but it's not working.

`df['A'] = df['A'].str.replace(" ","")`

Can someone help to fix this error ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is more than one space and to convert try:

```
df['A'] = df['A'].str.replace(r'\s+','', regex=True).astype(int)
```

Answer (score 1):

Improving on MDR's answer and showing another approach, you can use a function to convert the series to a series of integers. In this function, you would fix the problems in the current representation and return an integer. If unexpected errors are encountered, the function will return 0 and print the erroneous value. Code is as below.
import re

```
# define the function
def clean_A(a):
    try:
        return int(re.sub('\s+', '', a))
    except ValueError as e:
        print(f"errorneous value encountered {a}")
        return 0

# apply this function on the series
df['A'].apply(lambda x: clean_A(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

Clear spaces by:

```
df['A'] = df['A'].str.strip()
```